# How to make tables unavailable for users during certain times in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Iam a student and one of the questions i am stuck is to implement an IT management rule on all tables in oracle in my own schema using pl/sql.I dont have DBA previlege and the requirement is that on fridays from 08:00-09:00 none of the tables should be available and should display message saying its maintainance time. so basically I have prevent myself from accessing the tables in my schema during those times. I have used the following DML trigger for insert,update and delete

```
create or replace TRIGGER test_trig

 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employees
 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DY')='THU' AND
(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI'))BETWEEN '20:25' AND '20:30')

DECLARE
 e_invalid_time EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
 //DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' Tables are unavailable at this time.Please try again 
later'); 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'You may insert'
||' into EMPLOYEES table only during '
||' normal business hours.');

EXCEPTION
WHEN e_invalid_time THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' Tables are unavailable at this time.Please try again 
later');
 END test_trig;
```

But this will only be effective on one table. And SELECT queries will be still performed.I have about 6 tables
I read Fine grain auditing will help with select and all DML commands. what is the bet approach?This is for educational purposes.

Comment: `TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DY')='THU'` depends on current user NLS-Settings. You could easily bypass the trigger with a simple `alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'German';` and your condition never becomes TRUE. Use `TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = american')='THU'`

Comment: It doesn't matter if *you* don't have DBA privilege. *Someone* at your organisation will have the privileges necessary to implement the solution you design. (If *no-one* has DBA privileges, then your org has bigger problems to deal with)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the database in a [Quiesced State (Oracle Database Administrator's Guide)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start004.htm#ADMIN10263)

Restrict access. Only DBAs will be able to access the DB (i.e. user SYS or SYSTEM):

```
ALTER SYSTEM QUIESCE RESTRICTED;
```

Restore the database to normal operation:

```
ALTER SYSTEM UNQUIESCE;
```

Comment: Thanks. But  I dont have DBA previlege. I can do DDL triggers for all DDL commands and DML triggers on all tables to restrict all DML operations during those times. But still no luck with restricting select.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the error message in a function

```
create or replace function access_denied return number is
begin
  raise_application_error(-20001,'No access during this time');
end;
/
```

That can be invoked conditionally via a predicate.

```
select * from all_users
where case when to_char(sysdate,'HH24') = '23' then access_denied end is null
```

You can use [security policies](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/virtual-private-databases) to automatically apply that predicate or only give data access to users via views that include that clause.

In a real-world environment, any time constraint on user activity needs to consider what you do with users who are in the middle of a transaction at that time. If you don't terminate the transaction, the user (and database) may be stuck with a lock they can't do anything about. As such, often the only practical choice is to disconnect any active user sessions and stop them logging on.